# Injecting an Instance Fails with Kotlin & Guice

Tags: guice, kotlin

I have the following code:

```
class Test {

  private val context = Context().apply {
    property = "foo"
  }

  private val injector = Guice.createInjector(Module { it.bind(Context::class.java).toInstance(context) })

  @Test
  fun `service received correct context`() {
    assertThat(injector.getInstance(Service::class.java).context.property, equalTo("foo"))
  }

}

class Service @Inject constructor(val context: Context)

class Context {
  @Inject lateinit var property: String
}
```

When running it, the test fails, complaining (rightfully) that an empty string is not “foo.” But why is Guice not using the instance I painstakingly created and supplied to the injector in form a `Module`? (That’s the first question.)

However, if I change the `Context` to look like this:

```
class Context {
  @get:Inject lateinit var property: String
}
```

the test is suddenly succeeding. I don’t really understand why Guice is looking at `Context`’s annotations at all if I have bound the `Context` class to the instance I created. Can anybody tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guice automatically injects instances passed to `toInstance()` in a bind statement, so `@Inject` annotations on `Context` are relevant.

In your example, Guice is not creating a new instance of `Context`, but injects the field of the instance with an empty string.

When you annotate the property, Kotlin puts the annotation on the field. When you annotate the getter, Guice ignores it.

Comment: When using `private val injector = Guice.createInjector(Module { it.bind(Context::class.java).toProvider { context } })` it finally behaves the way I intended to. Thanks!